# How to load local files from user selected directory in chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am developing chrome app , in my app user can download external content to their local directory , to access user's file system i am using ***chrome.FileSystem*** API ,i can access user's local directory and i am also able to write downloaded content to their directory by keeping user selected directory to localStorage.

My problem is i want to open these files in main html file using either webview / iframe , it will be better if its possible with iframe but i am getting error in both cases -

to get full path i am using below code -

```
chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath(chosenEntry, function(path) {
      console.log("path"+path);
      // for now i am adding static path to it for testing purpose 
      var finalPath = path+'/folder/index.html'; //Here finalPath is a valid path , can be accessible from browser

});
```

if i load it using iFrame -

> Refused to frame 'path' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' blob: filesystem: data: chrome-extension-resource:".

When i tried using webview -

> : The load has aborted with error -301: ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME.

I have also tried by giving permission in manifest.json file -

```
"permissions": [
    "file:///*"
]
```

> Note : user may have number of downloaded content each with their own folder , so i have to open any of these according to user action.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but running a [web server](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome) inside chrome your chrome app and pointing the webview at the web server URL will work.

Comment: Thanks for your response , is there any other method ?

Comment: Well you could read the base html file into JS and then dump that into innerHTML, while rewriting all images to use base64 data urls, etc. It would be super hacky, but would work for small, simple pages.

Comment: This is not going to solution in our case, as i need different context and also a page may contain many script itself

Comment: You could parse out script src tags and read the js contents and put them inline into script tags probably too... again, I would not recommend this route